# Excel VBA Chart Not Recognizing Values

Tags: vba, graph, excel, charts

I have another pretty perplexing problem that one of you might be able to solve. So basically I have this code to write a line graph using Excel VBA. It's made so it can be dynamic and can change if more values are added. But it's reading the first value as 0 and the last value as 0 even though they are not 0. Here is the code I'm using to put the graph on the page.

```
Sub createchart4()

lastA = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Main!$A$1:$A$" & lastA)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Main!$A$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Main!$A$3:$A$" & lastA

End Sub
```

It's saying that A3's value is 0 when it's actually 1534 and it's also reading A10 and A11 as 0 also when they're different as well.

If you can figure this out, I would be amazed :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only scenario when a Chart ignores a number is when the number is stored as text. See Snapshot

[image]

How to know if the number is stored as text and how do we rectify it?

If you are using **Excel 2003** then go to menu `Tools | Options`. Under the `Error Checking` Tab, ensure that the checkbox `Number Stored as text` is checked.

In **Excel 2007/2010**, click on `Excel Options` which can be accessed from the `Office Icon` in **Excel 2007** or `Options` in the `File` Tab in **Excel 2010**.

Go to the `Formulas` tab and ensure that `Numbers formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe` is checked.

If the above checkbox is checked then you will notice a small **Green Triangle** as shown in the snapshot above. Select the entire range starting from the **1st cell** which has the **Green Triangle**. Click on the `Exclamation mark`. Click on `Convert to number` and you are done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your indepth and thought out response, and on my last question xD. Just an update, even though this was a brilliant idea, it was not the problem. I made a module that would take all the values and make them equal to itself. Silly I know, but is was the only thing that worked. Thank You!!

Comment: Where did the data come from? Was it imported from womewhere outside of Excel? Before you ran this little macro, were the cells formatted as text? Were the contents left-justified like text or right-justified like numbers?